# Pre-defined fields for nested attribute in nested form using checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model **Food** that has many **food_varients**. The **FoodVarient** is a model that will be set by the admin of the system. **For Example** the food varients could be **Hot,Spicy,Extra Cheese,** etc. And a food can have these varients.

Since, **Food** has_many **food_varients**, I decided to use nested form to allow the admin to create a new **food item** and also select **food_varients** that the food might have from the pre-defined **food_varients** created before-hand by the admin.

This is what my `FoodsController` looks like:

```
class FoodsController < DashboardBaseController

  # GET /foods/new
  def new
    @food = current_department.foods.new
    @food.food_varients.build
  end

  # GET /foods/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def food_params
    params.require(:food).permit(:name, :description,food_varients_attributes[:id,:varient_id])
  end

end
```

I have also accepted the nested attribute in my `Food.rb` file as follows:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :food_varients, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :varients, through: :food_varients, dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_varients, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['varient_id'] == "0" }
```

And this is what my form looks like, to add food:

```
= form_for @food do |f|
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 1
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 3
   ........

//**Nested Form Starts from here**
    - current_department.varients.each do |varient|
      = f.fields_for :food_varients do |g|
        = g.label :varient_id, varient.title
        = g.check_box :varient_id,{} ,varient.id
```

I created the nested form by looping around each instance of the **Varient** model, that was created by the admin, and giving the admin the options to add the **food_varients** as the new food item is being created.

**Problem:**

The create is working fine, and the nested attributes are being saved as expected.
But, when i try to edit the **food item**, the nested form is showing duplicate fields. 
**For Example:** If originally the food was set to have varients (sweet, and sour). Now, the edit page of the food item is showing me 4 fields instead of the two, with two checked sweet and sour fields, and two unchecked. sweet and sour fields.

Is there a different approach that i must be trying? Because ever other example that i see, makes the use of **text_fields** to save the nested attribute dynamically, while I am looping through the already existing **varient** instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use nested attributes at all here. Just use the collection helpers along with the `varient_ids=` setter:

```
= form_for @food do |f|
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 1
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', tabindex: 3
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :varient_ids
    = f.collection_select :varient_ids, Varient.all, :id, :name
```

```
class FoodsController < DashboardBaseController
  # GET /foods/new
  def new
    @food = current_department.foods.new
  end

  # ...

  def food_params
    params.require(:food).permit(:name, :description, varient_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Rails will automatically add/destroy rows on the join table. The correct spelling is also Variant:

> variant (*plural* **variants**)
>
> *Something that is slightly different from a type or norm.*
>   - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variant#English